# C++ header and implementation files, error: 'cv' has not been declared

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and I've been trying to create a separate header and implementation file for a simple open cv project. The errors I'm getting are:

- Robot.h:6:36: error: ‘raspicam’ has not been declared
- Robot.h:6:58: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
- Robot.cpp:3:42: error: ‘raspicam’ has not been declared
- Robot.cpp:4:2: error: ‘Camera’ was not declared in this scope
- Robot.cpp:4:13: error: ‘cv’ has not been declared

Any suggestions would help, thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

**File: Robot.h**

```
#ifndef ROBOT_H
#define ROBOT_H

class Robot {
    public:
    void setup(int argc, char **argv, raspicam::RaspiCam_Cv &Camera);
};

#endif
```

**File: Robot.Cpp**

```
#include "Robot.h"
void Robot::setup(int argc, char **argv, raspicam::RaspiCam_Cv &Camera) {
    Camera.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, ("-w",argc,argv,400));
    Camera.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, ("-h",argc,argv,240));
    Camera.set(cv::CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNESS, ("-br",argc,argv,50));
    Camera.set(cv::CAP_PROP_CONTRAST, ("-co",argc,argv,50));
    Camera.set(cv::CAP_PROP_SATURATION, ("-sa",argc,argv,50));
    Camera.set(cv::CAP_PROP_GAIN, ("-g",argc,argv ,50));
    Camera.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FPS, ("-fps",argc,argv, 0));
}
```

**File: main.cpp**

```
#include "Robot.h"

cv::Mat frame;
raspicam::RaspiCam_Cv Camera;
Robot bot;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    bot.setup(argc, argv, Camera);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you need to `#include` whatever files define the `raspicam` and `cv` namespaces.

Comment: How is `Robot.h` supposed to know what the `raspicam` namespace is? The precompile step takes care of text substitution. For your `main.cpp` (or `robot.cpp`), replace (not literally, do this in your head) any instance of `#include "Robot.h"` with the exact literal text of the `Robot.h` file. Then, the compile reads the "new file" from top to bottom. If it finds any symbols that haven't been declared, it can't use them.

Comment: `#include "raspicam"`? --> find out where raspicam is implemented and include that header in your robot.h

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Here's my suggestion: try separating header from implementation in a *much simpler project,* before you attempt it with something this complex. `HelloWorld` is a good place to start.